# How to use FirebaseFirestoreSwift for read Custom objects

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) but still getting error `expected argument type 'FirestoreSource'`. My Xcode target is 15.0. and Firebase version 8.15.0 (SPM)

```
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
     func getUser() -> User {
            let docRef = db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser)
            docRef.getDocument(as: User.self) { result in      //error: expected argument type 'FirestoreSource'
                switch result {
                case .success(let user):
                    print(user)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error decoding: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the custom object User.

```
struct User: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var username: String = ""
    var email: String = ""
    var family: [Family]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case username
        case email
        case family
    }
    
    struct Family: Codable, Hashable {
        var username: String = ""
        var phoneNumber: String = ""
        var email: String = ""

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case username
            case phoneNumber
            case email
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73636543/thread-1-exc-bad-instruction-when-fetching-data/73637713#73637713

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code

1 - The code attempts to use `Auth` without importing the FirebaseAuth. Please add

```
import FirebaseAuth
```

to the top with the rest of the imports

2 - This call

```
Auth.auth().currentUser
```

returns a firebase user object so it won't work here

```
let docRef = db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser)
```

you probably want to get the users uid

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser.uid
let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
```

3 - The function is set up to return a user

```
func getUser() -> User {
```

Firebase calls are asynchronous so a user (or anything else) cannot be returned in that fashion. A couple of options are to use a completion handler with an `@escaping` clause or the newer `async await` calls which would look like this to retrieve a specific document from a users collection and return the value of the 'name' field

```
func getUserAsync() async -> String{
    let usersCollection = self.db.collection("users")
    let thisUserDoc = usersCollection.document("uid_0")
    let snapshot = try! await thisUserDoc.getDocument()
    
    let name = snapshot.get("name") as? String ?? "No Name"
    
    return name
}
```

There are many references to both of those here on SO.