# Firebase function not getting called inside a forEach loop with a DispatchGroup

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, grand-central-dispatch

I apologize if this question is simple or the problem is obvious as I am still a beginner in programming.

I am looping over an array and trying to make an async Firestore call. I am using a DispatchGroup in order to wait for all iterations to complete before calling the completion.

However, the Firestore function is not even getting called. I tested with print statements and the result is the loop iterations over the array have gone through with an enter into the DispatchGroup each time and the wait is stuck.

```
func getUserGlobalPlays(username: String, fixtureIDs: [Int], completion: @escaping (Result<[UserPlays]?, Error>) -> Void) {    
    let chunkedArray = fixtureIDs.chunked(into: 10)
    var plays: [UserPlays] = []
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    
    chunkedArray.forEach { ids in
        
        group.enter()
        print("entered")
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            self?.db.collection("Users").document("\(username)").collection("userPlays").whereField("fixtureID", in: ids).getDocuments { snapshot, error in
                guard let snapshot = snapshot, error == nil else {
                    completion(.failure(error!))
                    return
                }
                for document in snapshot.documents {
                    let fixtureDoc = document.data()
                    let fixtureIDx = fixtureDoc["fixtureID"] as! Int
                    let choice = fixtureDoc["userChoice"] as! Int
                    plays.append(UserPlays(fixtureID: fixtureIDx, userChoice: choice))
                }
                group.leave()
                print("leaving")
            }
        }
    }
    group.wait()
    print(plays.count)
    completion(.success(plays))
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thread 1: EXC\_BAD\_INSTRUCTION when fetching data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73636543/thread-1-exc-bad-instruction-when-fetching-data)

Comment: Not really, I think I have issues related to the implementation of DispatchGroups , not sure though. Also, I am still not familiar with async await but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going on with your code I think you should fix. You were dangerously force-unwrapping document data which you should never do. You were spinning up a bunch of Dispatch queues to make the database calls in the background, which is unnecessary and potentially problematic. The database call itself is insignificant and doesn't need to be done in the background. The snapshot return, however, can be done in the background (which this code doesn't do, so you can add that if you wish). And I don't know how you want to handle errors here. If one document gets back an error, your code sends back an error. Is that how you want to handle it?

```
func getUserGlobalPlays(username: String,
                        fixtureIDs: [Int],
                        completion: @escaping (_result: Result<[UserPlays]?, Error>) -> Void) {
    let chunkedArray = fixtureIDs.chunked(into: 10)
    var plays: [UserPlays] = []
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    chunkedArray.forEach { id in
        group.enter()

        db.collection("Users").document("\(username)").collection("userPlays").whereField("fixtureID", in: id).getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                for doc in snapshot.documents {
                    if let fixtureIDx = doc.get("fixtureIDx") as? Int,
                       let choice = doc.get("choice") as? Int {
                        plays.append(UserPlays(fixtureID: fixtureIDx, userChoice: choice))
                    }
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error)
                
                // There was an error getting this one document. Do you want to terminate
                // the entire function and pass back an error (through the completion
                // handler)? Or do you want to keep going and parse whatever data you can
                // parse?
            }
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    
    // This is the completion handler of the Dispatch Group.
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(.success(plays))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are Dispatch queues not necessary regardless of how many calls? in this example, total calls in this function will be around 50 (500 fixtureIDs broken into arrays of 10, then a database call for each array) and I need them to fire in parallel if possible. Regarding force unwrapping and error handling, thank you for the tips but I haven't finished the function as I was occupied with the Dispatch group stuff. One last question if I may, in my original code, why is the database calls not going through and as a result no leaves are registered? Thank you

Comment: @Mbasa make sure you make a clear distinction between a Dispatch Group and a Dispatch Queue. The group is used to coordinate multiple async tasks with a single completion. The queue is used to perform work of any kind parallel to other queues, most importantly the main queue. You can, and in many cases should, use them together. The problem with spinning up a queue for each iteration is that it consumes too many queues for effectively a single task (the function). You want to dispatch tasks to the background (with queues) with careful consideration.

Comment: @Mbasa but you can use a Dispatch Group for any number of iterations, that's not going to be a problem. Whether you're making 2 loops or 2,000 loops, a single group will handle it just fine.

Comment: Appreciate the info, thank you. I have accepted the answer.

Comment: @Mbasa the reason yours didn't work was because you called `wait()` outside of the loop, not inside it. So after your first call to enter, you immediately called the group to wait and so it was waiting by the time the first call to leave was made. If you just move that call to wait inside the end of the for-each loop then it will work. But your code never calls `notify()` which is the completion handler of the entire group so all of the work inside the loop would be for nothing anyway.