# Loading data from Firebase returns empty snapshot when loggin in but other times returns correct values

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, closures

The app returns an empty snapshot when the logs in; however, if they click the reload button after logging in, it returns the correct snapshot. The same function downloadInitialUsers() is called when the view is loaded upon logging in, and when clicking the reload button. I am confused why the same query would return an empty snapshot at first, but then work as expected when clicking the reload button if its the same query! So when downloadUsersFromFirebase is called upon loading the view after logging in, my query returns an empty snapshot; but, when downloadUsersFromFirebase after clikcing reload, the query  does NOT return an empty snapshot.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("did load")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        emptyDataView.delegate = self
        downloadInitialUsers()
        setup()
    }
```

```
private func downloadInitialUsers() {
        ProgressHUD.show()

        FirebaseListener.shared.downloadUsersFromFirebase(isInitialLoad: isInitialLoad, limit: initialLoadNumber, lastDocumentSnapshot: lastDocumentSnapshot) { (allUsers, snapshot) in
            
            if allUsers.count == 0 {
                ProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
            
            self.lastDocumentSnapshot = snapshot
            self.isInitialLoad = false
            self.initialCardModels = []
            self.userObjects = allUsers
            let allUsersShuffle = allUsers.shuffled()
            
            for user in allUsersShuffle {
                print(user)
                user.getUserAvatarFromFirestore { (didSet) in
                    let cardModel = UserCardModel(id: user.objectId,
                                                  name: user.username)
                    self.initialCardModels.append(cardModel)
                    self.numberOfCardsChecked += 1
                    if self.numberOfCardsChecked == allUsers.count {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                            self.layoutCardStackView()

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            print("initial \(allUsers.count) received")
            self.downloadMoreUsersInBackground()
            
        }
    }
```

```
func downloadUsersFromFirebase(isInitialLoad: Bool, limit: Int, lastDocumentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot?, completion: @escaping (_ users: [FUser], _ snapshot: DocumentSnapshot?) ->Void) {
        
        var query: Query!
        var users: [FUser] = []
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        if isInitialLoad {
            query = FirebaseReference(.User).whereField(kTYPE, isEqualTo: "female").limit(to: limit)
            print("first \(limit) users loading")
            
        } else {
            
            if lastDocumentSnapshot != nil {
                query = FirebaseReference(.User).whereField(kTYPE, isEqualTo: "female").limit(to: limit).start(afterDocument: lastDocumentSnapshot!)
                
                print("next \(limit) user loading")

            } else {
                print("last snapshot is nil")
            }
        }
        
        if query != nil {
                guard let snapshot = snapShot else { return }
                
                if !snapshot.isEmpty {
                    
                    for userData in snapshot.documents {
                        
                        let userObject = userData.data() as NSDictionary
                        users.append(FUser(_dictionary: userObject))
                    }
                    users.shuffle()
                    completion(users, snapshot.documents.last!)
                    
                } else {
                    print("no more users to fetch")
                    users.shuffle()
                    completion(users, nil)
                }
                
            }
            
        } else {
            users.shuffle()
            completion(users, nil)
        }
    }
```

```
func didClickReloadButton() {
        let currentUser = FUser.currentUser()
        currentUser?.seenIdArray = []
        saveUserData(user: currentUser!)
        resetLoadCount()
        downloadInitialUsers()
        emptyDataView.reloadButton.isEnabled = false
    }
```

- Tried to catch an error in the query (no errors)
- Tried changing the query to load all users, same issue happened

Comment: Likely a timing issue you are calling asynchronous functions and expecting them to work synchronously. Look into async await fire ase has provided Concurrent alternatives to most of its functions and it will work similarly to what you are expecting.

Comment: Could you give an example of such a function ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73636543/thread-1-exc-bad-instruction-when-fetching-data/73637713#73637713

Comment: What happens when you move the database call from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear`? If nothing changes, what happens when you move it to `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: it finally worked, I just had to add a completion block when logging in