# How to pass user data with swiftui

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am learning how to pass data from screen to screen by fetching user data from firebase with swiftui. I have created a class with observable object to fetch the current user data but I am not receiving the updated data or any errors. What is the correct way to fetch the current user data ?

What am I missing from this code that's not allowing me to fetch my user data and how can I rewrite this code to successfully update my user screens with the current user data

```
class UserDataFile: ObservableObject {
  func FetchUser() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
      let db = Firestore.firestore()
      let docRef = db.collection("user").document("ProfileImages")

      docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
          let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
          print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        } else {
          print("Document does not exist")
        }
      }
```

```
struct AccountView: View {
@StateObject var userDataHere = UserDataFile()

var body: some View {
  ScrollView {
    NavigationView {
    }
    Button {
      AddFirebase()
      FetchUser()
    }label: {
      Text("Save")
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .environmentObject(userDataHere)
        .onAppear { userDataHere.FetchUser() }
    }
  }

  func FetchUser() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
      let db = Firestore.firestore()
      let docRef = db.collection("user").document("ProfileImages")

      docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
          let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
          print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        } else {
          print("Document does not exist")
        }
      }
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

```
struct ProfileHeader: View {
  @StateObject var userDataHere = UserDataFile()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
      Button {
      } label: {
        NavigationLink(destination: AccountView()) {
          Text("Account")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .environmentObject(userDataHere)
            .onAppear { userDataHere.FetchUser() }
        }
```

Comment: Hey, I updated the formatting of your code to make it a bit more readable but it's still quite hard to see what it's doing. There appears to be a missing `struct ViewName: View {` in the second code snippet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73636543/thread-1-exc-bad-instruction-when-fetching-data/73637713#73637713

Comment: you already asked that question before, why did you delete it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75710950/how-to-fetch-user-data

Comment: I added the struct its the view screen that allow my user to add their data to firebase @Fogmeister

Comment: hey check out the updated version @workingdogsupportUkraine

Answer (score 0):

To pass the data screen to screen you need to make sure you are referencing the same ObservableObject in every view. You seem to be initialising

@ObservedObject var userDataHere = UserDataFile()

in every view and this will lead to a new object with initial values, not values set in the previous view. The top of the hierarchy should have an @StateObject that initialises the observable and then this should be passed to each child view as a dependancy.

eg.

```
StateObject var userDataHere = UserDataFile()
   var body: some View {
      ProfileHeaderView(userDataHere: self.userDataHere)
   }

struct ProfileHeader: View {
    @ObservedObject var userDataHere: UserDataFile
    ....
```

Comment: I added stateObject but I still didn't receive my data @Hongtron

Comment: I have updated the code in the comment above. In editing I seemed to have made the same mistake. You will see in ProfileHeader view the userDataHere variable is declared with just the type, not a new object (ie. it is not set with = UserDataFile() ) which would create a new object independent to the StateObject in calling view). In the body where ProfileHeaderView us called the StateObject is passed in the initialiser to set the variable in ProfileHeaderView.

Comment: It is quite hard to see where you are calling the various views. I may be misunderstanding your question looking at it again. It seems the main problem that the fetch function is not getting any data. I also see in those functions you do not seem to be saving any dat returned to a variable within the Object. Is anything printing out from those functions. The let dataDescription = .... is just local to the function. It is quite hard to see where you are facing the issue accessing data.