# Firestore Swift Fetching Subcollection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am having a lot of trouble fetching data from my exerciseSet collection. It is a subset of my users collection. The exercise snapshot does not exist but it is finding the exercise document ID.

[image]
[image]
This is what the struct looks like:

```
struct fbExerciseSet: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var reps: Int
    var weight: Int
    var time: Int
    var dateCompleted: Date
    var exercise: fbExercise
}
```

I have tested a modification where I got rid of the exercise component so I only returned the exerciseSet ID and that returned the 2 exerciseSets I have saved in firestore. So the issue seems to be with referencing the exercise subcollection and returning as fbExercise. I have tried so many things and I am really stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my current function that is not returning any results in exerciseSetList:

```
func getExerciseSets2() {
        guard let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            print("User is not logged in.")
            return
        }
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("users").document(currentUserID).collection("exerciseSet")
            .getDocuments { snapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error fetching exercise sets:", error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                    print("Snapshot is nil.")
                    return
                }
                
                var exerciseSets: [fbExerciseSet] = []
                let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup() // Declare the dispatch group
                
                for document in snapshot.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    
                    let reps = data["reps"] as? Int ?? 1
                    let weight = data["weight"] as? Int ?? 1
                    let time = data["time"] as? Int ?? 1
                    let dateCompleted = data["date"] as? Date ?? Date()
                    
                    if let exerciseRef = data["exercise"] as? DocumentReference {
                        dispatchGroup.enter()
                        
                        exerciseRef.getDocument { exerciseSnapshot, exerciseError in
                            defer {
                                dispatchGroup.leave()
                            }
                            
                            if let exerciseError = exerciseError {
                                print("Error fetching exercise:", exerciseError.localizedDescription)
                                return
                            }
                            
                            guard let exerciseSnapshot = exerciseSnapshot, exerciseSnapshot.exists else {
                                print("Exercise snapshot does not exist. Exercise ID:", exerciseRef.documentID)
                                return
                            }
                            
                            let exerciseData = exerciseSnapshot.data()
                            
                            let exercise = fbExercise(
                                id: exerciseSnapshot.documentID,
                                name: exerciseData?["name"] as? String ?? "",
                                musclegroup: exerciseData?["musclegroup"] as? String ?? "",
                                instructions: exerciseData?["instructions"] as? String ?? ""
                            )
                            
                            let exerciseSet = fbExerciseSet(
                                id: document.documentID,
                                reps: reps,
                                weight: weight,
                                time: time,
                                dateCompleted: dateCompleted,
                                exercise: exercise
                            )
                            
                            exerciseSets.append(exerciseSet)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                    // Update your exerciseSetList with the fetched exerciseSets
                    self.exerciseSetList = exerciseSets
                    print("COUNT: \(self.exerciseSetList.count)")
                }
            }
    }
```

I get all these errors:
Exercise snapshot does not exist. Exercise ID: GOkkx6b02NXG6XFVAtAI
COUNT: 0
printed to console

It is finding the Exercise ID I am expecting but the exercise snapshot does not exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thread 1: EXC\_BAD\_INSTRUCTION when fetching data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73636543/thread-1-exc-bad-instruction-when-fetching-data)

Comment: I may be overlooking something but the path shown in the screenshot is not valid. e.g. in the screenshot showing the `exerciseSet` document, that document has a property `exercise` that has a value starting with a path to `/exercises` (plural) but that path doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: @loremipsum no unfortunately, I have updated my question

Comment: @Jay thank you for catching that. I fixed that and am still having an issue which I updated the question to reflect.
Thank you!

Comment: There's some ambiguity which makes it hard to follow the troubleshooting. First: *exercise snapshot does not exist but it is finding the exercise document ID* - how do you know it'd finding the documentID if the snapshot is empty? e.g. nil documents do not exist. Second: *only returned the exerciseSet ID and that returned the 2 exerciseSets* - the screenshot only shows one doc within exerciseSets, not 2 so how did it return 2? Lastly: *Exercise snapshot does not exist* - is that thrown from the error block? We don't know what `exercise` path that's referring to but the path looks incorrect.

Comment: @Jay I see what you mean. I added this line: `print("Exercise snapshot does not exist. Exercise ID:", exerciseRef.documentID)` and the when I run it, Exercise snapshot does not exist. Exercise ID: GOkkx6b02NXG6XFVAtAI is printed to the console. This is the exercise ID I was expecting which exists in firestore so I am confused why it can find the document ID but there is an issue with the snapshot of the exercise in the document. Can you clarify what you mean by "path looks incorrect"? thanks!

Comment: also yes you are right about your 2nd point, I previously had 2 documents but deleted one and I am under a different user and forgot to delete that from the question sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Switch to using `DocumentReference` instead of searching for the references every time. I think evading