# Firebase showing warning when setData is used: consider using asynchronous alternative function

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Does somebody know why firebase show this warning: `Consider using asynchronous alternative function` all the time when I use the following code:

```swift
class UserServices {
    
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var doesUserIdExists = false
    
    static let shared = UserServices()
    
    func checkUsernameAvailability(newUsername: String, doesExists: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) async throws {
        db.collection("usernames").getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
           if let error {
               doesExists(true)
               print("Error getting users documents. Error: \(error)")
           } else {
               if let querySnapshot {
                   var usernames: [String] = []
                   for document in querySnapshot.documents {
                       let id = document.documentID
                       usernames.append(id)
                   }
                   doesExists(usernames.contains(newUsername))
                
               } else {
                   doesExists(false)
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

I think it's a pretty simple function, if I use `await`, it shows the waring that there were no async calls, so it's not needed. The code works as expected even though warnings stress me out. I'm quite new to Swift world,
any help is appreciated. I have seen other similar question but with no solution.

Comment: Completion handlers are the old methods, async await is safer and cleaner. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73636543/thread-1-exc-bad-instruction-when-fetching-data/73637713#73637713

Comment: @loremipsum that's how I'm working but it didn't let me put the await, says that it was unused.

Comment: You can’t just put await you have to remove the completion handler (brackets) it is much more linear.

Comment: @loremipsum I tried it like that but still said that, that's why I applied this approach, anyways ill keep researching, thanks.

Comment: We can’t help with what we can’t see.