# Firestore and Swift: Retrieving an array of documents from a collection

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections in Firestore:

- Workouts
- Exercises

The `workouts` collection is composed of a `name`, a `type` and an array of references to exercises in the `Exercise` collection.
The `workouts` collection looks like this:

[image]

My problem is that when I'm trying to get the workouts in the `Workouts` collection, I'm doing it like this:

```
let workoutDocuments = try await self.store.collection("/workouts").getDocuments().workoutDocuments
                for workoutDocument in documents {
let workoutCodable =  workoutDocument.data(as: WorkoutCodable.self)

// MARK: - WorkoutCodable
struct WorkoutCodable: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
//    var exercises: [ExerciseCodable]
    var name: String?
    var type: WorkoutTypeCodable
}
}
```

If the exercises array declaration is commented, then it all works fine. However, if remove the comment on the `var exercises: [ExerciseCodable]` then I have a problem:

> Error getting the benchmark workouts: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "exercises", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found FIRDocumentReference instead.", underlyingError: nil))

How can I fetch all those exercises stored in the `exercises` array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73636543/thread-1-exc-bad-instruction-when-fetching-data/73637713#73637713

Answer (score 2):

Firestore won't follow reference links for you and fill in the data from the referenced document.

The error says

> "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found FIRDocumentReference instead."

You said that `exercises` was an array of JSON objects (specially objects that can be turned into `ExerciseCodable` structs) but the decoding process found an array of `FIRDocumentReference`.

You need to update `WorkoutCodable` to reflect this and then once you have a `WorkoutCodable` you need to use the references to fetch the referenced documents from Firestore

```
struct WorkoutCodable: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var exercises: [FIRDocumentReference]
    var name: String?
    var type: WorkoutTypeCodable
}

let workoutCodable =  workoutDocument.data(as:WorkoutCodable.self)

for exerciseRef in workoutCodable.exercises {
   let exerciseCodable = exerciseRef.data(as:ExerciseCodable.self)
   // do something with exercise. 
}
```